# expand div in half page

Tags: html, css

I think i need some help..

It is a bit hard to explain, and my English is not the best but i will try..

Have got a eCommerce site and when i open a product page i have got 3 columns.

the left with the menus and newsletter, the right with "add to wish list" and a Paypal banner.. the main column shows the product title and add to cart.. and at very bottom shows the product description.. the thing is.. the product description just shows on the middle column. but i want to be able to expand to all page..

I truly need some on this..

Thanks in advance!

code css:

```
/* Left Content Area */

.Left {
    float: left;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 176px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    display: inline;
}

/* Primary Content Area */
.Content {
    float: left;
    width: 588px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    padding: 6px 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 0.95em;
}

/* Right Content Area */
.Right {
    float: right;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 176px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
display: inline;
```

}

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. In order to help you please provide some relevant code to reproduce the problem, at least some code and the live url or images.

Comment: We truly need your existing html and css to see the issue

Comment: please visit my site.. it is easier.. www.esales2u.co.uk open a random product and scroll down for product description..

Comment: That's the way is structured your HTML maybe you can't break that with some position arguments but is gonna be tricky, anyway you can't do what you want in a easy way without changing your html .

Comment: Please post the code here then it may help others in future with the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: I am using bigcommerce hosting.. and i just know a basics of html and css.. if i give you my admin details would you try to do that for me?

Comment: right.. i guess i have to find out by my self then..

Comment: can you just guide me for a solution please?

Comment: SO is a Q&A site where the community's answers can help one another. Edit your question and include the relevant code and hopefully somebody can help you.

Comment: i just add some code...

Answer (score -2):

set min-height to the height you want your column to stretch.

Comment: Please just not throw the answer.Did you even read the question carefully?